# The negation statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a statement such that:

> There exists a $\epsilon>0$ small enough, such that for all
>   $t\in[0,1]$ the statement $P$ hold.

I thought the negation of above statement was:

> There exists a sequences $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$,
>   $\epsilon_n\to 0$, and a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb
> > N}\subset[0,1]$ such that $P$ does not hold for each $n$

However, I realize later that the correct negation statement might be:

> There exists a $t_0\in[0,1]$ and a sequences $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n\in
> > \mathbb N}$, $\epsilon_n\to 0$, such that $P$ does not hold.

I am confused at those two negation statements. Which one is correct?

Comment: Why do you need sequences?  I'd think it'd be, for any epsilon there with exist a $t\in [0,1]$ so that the statement does not hold.  But I am probably missing a part of the problem you are not stating.

Answer (score 0):

Negation of "There exists a ϵ>0 small enough, such that for all t∈[0,1] the statement P hold."

Is "There does *not* exists  a ϵ>0 small enough, such that for all t∈[0,1] the statement P hold."

Is "For all $\epsilon > 0$ it is not the case that all $t\in [0,1]$ have the statement $P$ holds"

If "For every $\epsilon > 0$ there will be at least one $t\in [0,1]$ where the statement $P$ fails".

I have no idea we you are creating sequences of $\epsilon$ and $t$s.

Does the statement $P$ have something to do with statements?

But as to the statements you gave:

"There exists a sequences {ϵn}n∈N, ϵn→0, and a sequence {tn}n∈>N⊂[0,1] such that P does not hold for each n"

This does not negate the statement.  It is possible that the $\epsilon$ for which the statement holds for all $t$ is not among the sequence of $\epsilon$s.  The implication of the statment implies that once $P$ holds for all $t$ for any epsilon, it will hold for all $t$s with *any* smaller epsilon.  But that is only an implication.  It is NOT stated.  As it stands there is no stated relevence to the size of $\epsilon$ having any bearing on the statment hold.

If, however, the implication that if $P$ holds for all $t \in [0,1]$ for $\epsilon > 0$ then $P$ holds for all $t \in [0,1]$ for any smaller value of $\epsilon$ then this statement would be equivalent to my negation.

My negation $\implies$ this negation.  For $\epsilon > 0$ a $t\in [0,1]$ where $P$ fails.  Select corresponding sequences of $\epsilon_n, t_n$ where this is true.

This negation $\implies$ my negation.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\epsilon_n < \epsilon$ and a $t_n$ where the statement fails so my $\epsilon$ is not small enought to have $P$ hold for all $t$.

"There exists a t0∈[0,1] and a sequences {ϵn}n∈>N, ϵn→0, such that P does not hold."

This will negate the original statement but is too strong a statement.  The original statement could still be false even with the statement failing to hold for various different values of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The negation of
some r > 0 with for all t in [0,1], P(t)
is
for all r > 0, some t in [0,1] with not P(t).